# How to get Liferay user email address in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, liferay

I can able to get themeDisplay object in JavaScript.

**Refereed :** https://web.liferay.com/web/pankaj.kathiriya/blog/-/blogs/usage-of-liferay-js-object

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var userid=Liferay.ThemeDisplay.getUserId;
  alert(userid);
});
```

How to get `User email Address`?

Comment: `Liferay.themeDisplay.getUser().getDisplayEmailAddress();`

Comment: did you checked it?

Answer (score 1):

Liferay JS utility's `Liferay.ThemeDisplay` or just `themeDisplay` does not implicitly contain user's email address. It just exposes `userId` and `userName` while it doesn't have any `getUser` or `User` object in it.

However, you can achieve that by overridding `\html\common\themes\top_js.jspf` using JSP hook. All you need to do is to add following lines below `getUserName: function() {`:

```
getUserEmailAddress: function() {
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="<%= themeDisplay.isSignedIn() %>">
            return "<%= UnicodeFormatter.toString(user.getEmailAddress()) %>";
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            return "";
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
},
```

Then you will be able to get user's email address by either `Liferay.ThemeDisplay.getUserEmailAddress();` or `themeDisplay.getUserEmailAddress();`.

Comment: I am working on Liferay 7.. i need to write a liferay module fragment project, dough is which jar file the \html\common\themes\top_js.jspf

Comment: I would prefer to add this function in top_js-ext.jspf

Comment: I haven't worked on Liferay 7 yet, but you can find this file in `liferay-portal/portal-web/docroot/html/common/themes/top_js.jspf` and override it with suggested changes.

Comment: It depends, in our ext environment, we have directly changed this file. You can add these changes in `top_js-ext.jspf` as well, because this file will override the `top_js.‌​jspf`.